# Consulta LINQ para objeto com uma sub lista

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, linq

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
public class Insumo{
    public int Insumo_id { get; set; }
    public List<InsumoDados> Dados{ get; set; }
}

public class InsumoDados{
    public int Desc { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor{ get; set; }
}
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta no banco de forma que ela já me retorne uma lista da classe **Insumo**. De preferência com linq.
Algo tipo:

```
 var listInsumo = (from insumo in banco.orc_insumo                        
                    select new Insumo
                    {
                        Insumo_id = insumo.insumo_id,
                        .
                        .
                        .
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: Você criou `DbSet` de `Insumo` e `InsumoDados`?

Comment: Criei sim @Barbetta

Comment: To pelo Cel.. se der certo mais tarde deixo resposta, tente assim: `var lista = seuContexto.Insumos.Include(p=> p.Dados).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa é fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var listInsumo = seuContexto.Insumos.Include(p=> p.Dados).ToList();
```

Use o `Include` para fazer `join`, caso precise

Outra forma:

```
var listInsumo = from insumo in banco.orc_insumo                    
                select insumo;
```

<sub>obs: Não sei o nome do seu `DbSet` então pode ser que tenha que ajustar o nome das propriedades</sub>